# PHP error checking

Tags: php

how would you go about doing something like that?

```
#do something that may cause an $error
if (!$error) {
    #do something that may cause an $error
    if (!$error) {
        #do something that may cause an $error
        if (!$error) {
            #do something that may cause an $error
            if (!$error) {
            }
        }
    }

}

if ($error) {
    #error message
}
```

I'd say that's a better solution:

```
#do something that may cause an $error
if ($error) goto error;
#do something that may cause an $error
if ($error) goto error;
#do something that may cause an $error
if ($error) goto error;
#do something that may cause an $error
if ($error) goto error;

error:
if ($error) {
    #error message
}
```

any other ideas?

Comment: Euhm... I don't see how this is question.

Comment: It's both bad and should not ever be used.

Comment: This boils down to coding styles, and therefore has no solution except outright religious war.

Comment: well, I'm asking for better ways to do that

Comment: If I were you, I'd leave my fingers from goto.

Comment: You're asking for betther ways to do WHAT?

Comment: I wrote an article on this on [my blog](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2011/08/error-handling-in-php.html)...  But as far as the question itself, I think it could be constructive if worded right, but as set it is not...

Comment: What exactly r u trying to accomplish?

Comment: THIS IS FRIDAY! Why couldn't you post this on monday?

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($error){
   trigger_error('Your error', E_USER_ERROR);
}
#something
if ($error){
   trigger_error('Your error', E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: this isn't the same, because "#something" couldn't have run if an error had already happened

Comment: won't this still execute "#something" even if $error === true?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. I'd structure my script to use some logically try/catch blocks so I can handle errors without having to resort to massive if statements... and gotos... (You know my university prof's would give you an F and kick you out of your class if you put a GOTO statement on any script/code project?)

From the handy: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

// Continue execution
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

For your example:

```
#Do something
try
{
   #code for doing something.
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
  throw new Exception("error doing something", $ex);
}

#do something again, and again. this will only happen if the previous worked.
try
{
     #Ok let's try this again.
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
  throw new Exception("Again!?", $ex);
}
```

If an exception is thrown - it should/need to/please be caught  by another catch, or it will just spit out the error all over the user.

Answer (score 1):

do..while(false) and break:

```
do {

    #do something that may cause an $error
    if ($error) break;

    #do something that may cause an $error
    if ($error) break;

    #do something that may cause an $error
    if ($error) break;

    #do something that may cause an $error
    if ($error) break;

} while (false);

if ($error) {
    # handle error
}
```

It's actually an example from the PHP manual: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: I think that's worse than goto... it's like trying to use a goto, without using it

Comment: Eh, I think this is pretty clean **looking**, there's nothing "bad" about this.

Comment: @Lem0n right, it's a goto without goto :)

Answer (score 0):

`GoTo` is [Considered Harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html) (sorry, old joke) - but most of the time, it isn't needed. There are more flexible ways to handle errors, but it all largely depends on context.

There's nothing "wrong" with the nested if statements that you provided as an example, but could get a little hard to read if each block is long, easy to misplace a curly brace, thus harder to maintain.

You can just spread it out:

```
$error = false;

/* do something that might set $error to true */

if ($error === false) {
  /* continue the process, might set error to non-false (tip: pass an error message!) */
}
if ($error === false) {
  /* continue the process, might set error to non-false  */
}
if ($error === false) {
  /* continue the process, might set error to non-false  */
}
if ($error === false) {
  /* continue the process, might set error to non-false  */
}
if ($error !== false) {
  /* generic error handling (report to the user, etc) */
  echo 'There was an error: '.$error;
  die();
}

/* report success to the user */
```

I would not use true/false for the `$error`, but rather false for no error, or a short message describing the error. That will make debugging easier, and you can give your user a useful message.

Further, without knowing what you are doing, I would say that this seems like a clunky way to handle errors. Without seeing context, I can't say for certain, but it seems likely that if an upper portion of the script were to encounter an error, you wouldn't want to bother with the rest of the script.  Maybe better, then:

```
$error = false;
/* do something that might set $error to true */
if ($error !== false) return errorHandler($error);
// ... etc
```

Or maybe using an exception handler:

```
$error = false;
/* do something that might set $error to true */
if ($error !== false) throw new Exception($error);
// ... etc
```

As you can see, there's more than one way to skin this cat. It really, really, really depends on context, both within the particular function or procedure and within the project as a whole. It is vital to a project to have consistent error handling, so it pays to develop something that is reusable. The first route, with the block of nested ifs (or ifs in a big series) has the mark of an under-developed error handling system - it doesn't strike me as very systematic or flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all that fuss about goto.
why to add tons of useless operators just because of some weird superstition?

If you have your conditions depended on each other, then go for goto.

If it's all right to check them all, like in form validation - just check them all in turn.

Exceptions are OK too but of course NOT the general one which intended for the system errors, but specially designed exception, which wont interfere with others.

But the thing that amuses me so much is a different attitude towards these two operators - `throw` and `goto`. While latter one condemned forever as a foulest of sins, a former one at the same time worshiped as a holy grail.

While both doing exactly the same %)

Comment: "I don't understand all that fuss about goto." Neither did this guy: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: haha, it's a joke. Really though you're probably right. Even many "modern" programming languages still have the goto statement. See: http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Goto_statements -- it's there, although slightly more restricted than a traditional goto. I've also heard the argument that goto is often preferred to exceptions because at least it's 100% deterministic if you hit a goto.